# Symfony2 / Doctrine2: catch QueryException and output query

Tags: debugging, symfony, doctrine-orm

When having errors in my queries, the exception which is thrown by Symfony2 is, in most cases, not very helpful, because it lacks the context, that is: the query which triggered the error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 74: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'd'

Is there a way to do something like that:

```
... catch(\Exception $exception){
if(get_class($exception) == 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'){
    /* var $exception \Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException */
    var_dump($exception->getSqlQuery());
}
...
```

That would improve debugging A LOT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should now be built-in doctrine, since this commit https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/d05ad996c4c3acfd3a0c8659719dd4752cb84531 (commited in master).
I guess it may be release in doctrine 2.3